# Query using Entity Framework using input by textbox

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to query my database using Entity Framework, but I receive the following error:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

This is the relevant code part:

```
string gendercode = txtGenderNo.Text;

using (var dbcontext = new Entities())
{
    var GenderName = dbcontext
                     .Genders
                     .Where(u => u.Code == Convert.ToInt32(gendercode))
                     .Select(u => u.GenderType)
                     .SingleOrDefault();
    txtGenderName.Text = GenderName;
}

public int Code { get; set; }
public string GenderType { get; set; }

public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Gender> Genders { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<sysdiagram> sysdiagrams { get; set; }
```

Comment: Also I would modify your query this way:

`var GenderName = dbcontext.Genders.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Code == Convert.ToInt32(gendercode)).GenderType;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your `gendercode` outside the query.

```
        string gendercode = txtGenderNo.Text;
        using (var dbcontext = new Entities())
        {
            var something = Convert.ToInt32(gendercode);
            var GenderName = dbcontext
                     .Genders
                     .Where(u => u.Code == something)
                     .Select(u => u.GenderType)
                     .SingleOrDefault();
            txtGenderName.Text = GenderName;
        }
```

It should work this way.

Answer (score 4):

Entity Framework tries to translate your C# code into SQL. Not everything is translatable - only a certain subset is supported by the Entity Framework driver. In your case the solution is easy: convert `genderCode` to `int` before the LINQ query and use that value in the query:

```
var genderCodeAsInt = Convert.ToInt32(gendercode);
using (var dbcontext = new Entities())
{
    var GenderName = dbcontext
                     .Genders
                     .Where(u => u.Code == genderCodeAsInt)
                     .Select(u => u.GenderType)
                     .SingleOrDefault();
            txtGenderName.Text = GenderName;
}
```